# Creating inline function in header class to a private variable

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, linked-list, header-files

I have to make a linked list. I'm not sure if I'm doing this right first of all. But basically the project says I'm not allowed to make a .cpp file but I have to create 4 inline statements through the .h file.

```
class Queue{
private:
struct QueueNode{
    int size;
    std::string party;
    QueueNode *next;
};
QueueNode *front;
QueueNode *rear;
public:
// Constructor
Queue();

// Destructor
~Queue();

// Queue operations
std::string getPartyName() const { return party; } // This and next 3 lines give error with the private variables
int getSize() const { return size; }
void setPartyName(std::string p) const{ party = p; }
void setSize(int s) const{ size = s; }
};
```

Comment: `party` and `size` are not member of `Queue` but `QueueNode`. So those four function should not be member function of `Queue`. Or maybe you want the values of the first node of `Queue`. Then you need to modify the body of those function and fetch the value from `front` after proper null check

Comment: @kuro if that's the case. Would making the first return statement into `return QueueNode*->party;` (Sorry still new to linked list)

Comment: almost. It should be `return front->party`. `QueueNode` is a type, `front` is your member variable of that type. You can't dereference a type. Also, the return statement should be followed by a null check of `front`. Another thing is are those your only member functions of `Queue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are halfway there. You need to declare the functions in the header file, as you have done.

The missing step is that you need to not define the functions within the class body but instead define them below the class declaration using the class name with the scope resolution operator and the inline operator.

The other piece you are missing is that you are declaring functions in your Queue class that are likely meant for your QueueNode struct.

```
class Queue{
private:
struct QueueNode{
    int size;
    std::string party;
    QueueNode *next;
};

   QueueNode *front;
   QueueNode *rear;
   public:
   // Constructor
   Queue();

   // Destructor
   ~Queue();

   // Queue operations
   std::string getPartyName( const QueueNode * const node ) const; 
   int getSize( const QueueNode * const node ) const;
   void setPartyName( QueueNode & out_node, std::string & p);
   void setSize( QueueNode & out_node, int s);
};

inline std::string Queue::getPartyName( const QueueNode * const node ) const 
{
   return node->party;
}

inline int getSize( const QueueNode * const node ) const {
   return node->size;
}

inline void Queue::setPartyName( QueueNode & out_node, std::string & p) {
   out_node.party = p;
}

inline void Queue::setSize( QueueNode & out_node, int s) {
   out_node.size = s;
}
```

It isn't clear what nodes you intend to set these values for, so I'll fill in the functions with some assumptions.

Either way I think you get the point. If you want to define inline functions within a header class, you cannot define the body within the class itself. You must declare it inline, which is a **compiler suggestion**, outside the body of the class. I know I didn't complete define the functionality of a linked list, I will leave that to you. But, this should answer the inline question.

Comment: I'll try this out. I'm still not sure what a linked list does 100% but I appreciate the help!

Comment: A linked list a connection of Ptrs that point to other Ptrs of the QueueNode to form a connection of pointers. If you want to implement a linked list, first you need to instantiate the QueueNode ptrs so they aren't pointing to garbage and add functions to add another QueueNode * to the front or back of the list. Bonus points if you implement functions for insertions in the middle. Btw, you will probably want to move the size variable to be a part of the Queue class to keep track of the size of the linked list. If this answer helped, I would appreciate an accept.

Comment: Ah ok! I guess it's good also because it reduces the size used compared with a fixed array. You only use the data you need to use unlike an array. Also, in your code, how would you pass an argument from the main function? `Queue test; test.setSize(arg1,arg2);`? what would an argument be for a linked list?

Comment: I don’t think setsize is a good function with linked list. Think of it as adding a ptr to part of the connections. AddNodeToEnd( QueueNode * nodeToAdd ) { front->next = nodeToAdd; front = nodeToAdd; }

Comment: I have the setSize in order to set the of the party, meaning like 20 people in that party. :) I think I got the rest figured out now, and I highly appreciate the help!

Comment: No problem! Good luck. Strings are typically implemented as arrays so you can always query the size of a string unless you are using that to preallocate memory